# "Hock the Rembrandt"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

I read that expression recently. It was used more or less as follows:

> It is very expensive: so, if you really want to acquire it, be prepared
>   to hock the Rembrandt.

I would like to know if this is a fixed expression used regularly in some parts of the English-speaking world... Going out on a limb I daresay that this expression comes from or is related to an idiom in Dutch. Am I right or dead wrong?

Comment: Never heard of this. are you sure this is common usage of words?

Comment: What do you mean by "common usage of words"?

Comment: It’s not an established idiom (that I’m aware of, anyway), but using _Rembrandt_ (i.e., an original painting by the famous Dutch artist) as an archetypical example of ‘something extremely valuable/expensive’ is not uncommon. It’s similar to saying, “be prepared to sell grandma’s jewellery”: not an idiom as such, but easily understandable. (Of course, this one is more humorous, because it’s assuming that normal people just happen to have a Rembrandt hanging around the house, waiting to be hocked off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the painter [Rembrandt van Rijn](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt_van_Rijn) and, curiously enough, the 
word *[hok](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hok)* (animal pen, shed), upon which the English *in hock* and *to hock* are derived, are both Dutch, the expression betrays a hyperbole typical of expressions in English describing something extremely expensive.

A Google [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hock%20the%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chock%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhock%20the%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhock%20the%20ring%3B%2Cc0) searching for the word most likely to follow *hock the* yielded only two significant hits: *ring*, in almost all cases someone pawning a ring for quite serious reasons, and — *family*. This reveals the pattern of your expression:

To buy that, you'd have to hock the family

> [jewels](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hock%20the%20family%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chock%20the%20family%20jewels%3B%2Cc0) (by far the winner), gems; silver, silverware, plate; farm, estate, etc.

To follow the pattern, one must simply substitute some object of extreme value, such as a Rembrandt painting, to convey the same meaning.